# Should doors over carpeting be hung higher than those over hard floors?

Tags: doors

A joiner recently hung doors in my house but 2 x bedroom doors where the carpet will be fitted hang higher than the surrounding doors. 
The timber frames are also about 1.5 inches higher.
After the doors have the framing around them and the carpet is fitted will I even notice this? 
I am currently worried my house is going to look ridiculous

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Obviously doors over carpet need to be hung higher so the gap is similar throughout the home (though not usually 1.5" higher--more like 1"). What's the question?

Comment: I had my old metal door frames removed and new wooden frames put in.   All 5 doors upstairs are the same length so I assumed all the new door frames would be aligned accross the top in height. What I currently have is 2 x door frames higher than the other 3, when I asked about this the joiner said this was to accommodate the carpet. He explained that this would be resolved when he puts the frames round the outside of the doors as he would round them all at the same height.  is this the case?  I want to make sure what he tells me is correct before the plastering gets done.

Comment: He may be planning to trim the doors to final height

Comment: @Jon, not if the frames were set differently. Laura, what do you mean by "round at the same height"?

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question refers primarily to the top of the door.

Answer (score 0):

The tops of the doors should all be in a perfect line with each other. (Often the tops of windows align with this also). The bottoms of the doors could be cut differently to clear whatever flooring there is. This is only for aesthetics but is an important visual detail.

Comment: I would agree if the doors are within a few feet of each other. Most people can't discern three quarters of an inch to an inch of variation across a room or between rooms. In many years of building high end custom homes, we almost never cut the bottoms of doors off. Honestly, the variation in knob height that would create would be more annoying.